# How to get the beginning date of a month from mysql table

Tags: mysql, date, find

I have a MYSQL 8.0 table which has dates.  From this table i need to get the first date of each month.

```
DATE_COLUMN

2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-04
2013-01-06
2013-01-31
2013-02-03
2013-02-07
2013-02-27
2013-03-01
2013-03-21

    RESULT
    2013-01-02
    2013-02-03
    2013-03-01
```

How to do this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Good sample data. Can you show us what you've already tried and the results?

Answer (score -1):

If your dates are already sorted `uniq` can do it, e.g.:

```
<infile uniq -w7
```

Output:

```
2013-01-02
2013-02-03
2013-03-01
```